# function named to_ransom_case that returns each character has been randomly transformed to either uppercase or lowercase in python

Tags: python, random

Create a function named to_ransom_case that accepts a single
string argument (a message) and returns the message after each character has been
randomly transformed to either uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: `def to_ransom_case(s): return "".join(chr(ord(c) + random.choice([0,32])) if c.isalpha() else c for c in s.upper())`

Comment: `def to_random_case(s): return ''.join([i.upper() if random.choice([0, 1]) else i.lower() for i in list(s)])`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import random


def to_ransom_case(s):
    return_string = ""
    for letter in s:

        if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
            return_string += letter.capitalize()
        else:
            return_string += letter.lower()
    return return_string
```

It goes through everey letter in the word and then randomize whether it will be capitalized or lower cased.